# How to Include JavaScript variable in Django URL in template?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to include mangaid variable in "{% url 'manga' mangaid %}".  Neither ${mangaid} nor mangaid works. How can I do this?

```
   let input = document.querySelector("#search")
    input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
      document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = "";
      let value = (input.value)
      fetch(`searchresponse/${value}`).then((response) => response.json()).then((results) => {
        results.forEach(function (result) {
          let mangaid = (result["id"])
          document.querySelector("#results").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<a class="result" id="result${mangaid}">${result["title"]}</a>`);
          document.getElementById("result"+mangaid).addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            event.target.href = "{% url 'manga' mangaid %}"
          })
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: If you include the script in `<script>` tags within your HTML template that you will render, then `{% url 'manga' mangaid %}` should work.  If this is in an external js file, then it will not, since Django will not be rendering that.  In that situation, you will need to fetch the variables from the server, and have the server return a JsonResponse response, from which your JavaScript can extract the data.

Comment: Oh, that was exactly my issue.

Comment: So JsonResponse should be the string of {% url 'manga' mangaid(which is actual value) %} ?

Comment: No, it's more complicated.  First your js file would [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the data from a view.  This view would send back a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) like `response = JsonResponse({'mangaid': manga.pk})`, back to your js file, which would get the response, with the sought after data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using get params f.e. `http://localhost:8000/manga/?a=1`.
In the view you can access get params via `request.GET.get('a')`, in this case the code would return 1 from a=1 in the url.

In JS with djangos url templatetag you can do `fetch("{% url 'manga' %}/mangaid=" mangaid)...`.
Django will replace `{% url 'manga' %}` with the url named manga.
mangaid needs to be a js variable.

Your view head should look similiar to this:

```
def mangaView(request):
    mangaid = request.Get.get('mangaid')
    print(mangaid)
```

EDIT:
Url should have trailing / to prevent redirects (301), this reduces server load (important in prod) `http://localhost:8000/abc/?a=1`.